# angular 6 How do I get url relatively as string

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6, router

I have the url string of the current page

using `_router.url`

```
> localhost:4200/School/12300/Demography/12345
```

but I need to remove the end of the url from Demography till end like:

```
> localhost:4200/School/12300
```

How can I do this simply? (without split and foreach functions)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I relized I can use relatively path like `"../../"`

and this can work always, even if I don't have the full path.

Thanks!

Comment: If this answer is correct and solved your problem please mark as answer.